# How to move the sound notification on 17.10?

Tags: sound

How can I move the volume notification on 17.10?
I don't like the fact that its placed on the bottom center, especially when I'm watching subtitled movies...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Move OSD Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1220/move-osd-windows/) extension, to change the location of the volume/brightness OSD popups.